# Do's and Don't's of Undergraduate Research

Tags: research-undergraduate

I was fortunate enough to get a position as a researcher for the Mayo Clinic's SURF Program this year. My PI's lab focus is on the the immune system's role in CNS axonal and neuronal injury, specifically through the lens of how innate and adaptive immune effectors interact w/ infected neurons.

Although I do research under a professor at my college and I volunteered for a state university lab during the previous summer, this is my first REU/SURF opportunity, and I REALLY want to make a good impression. Here are my questions:

What are the do's and don't's in terms of being a skilled and efficient researcher?

Since I am still an undergrad, I know that I will be a less useful asset to the lab than a grad student or post-doc, but what can I do as an undergrad to not burden my colleagues and PI?

Thank you all for your help! Wishing you all the very best!

Comment: I wish more people asked questions like this.

Comment: I've removed "biomedical" from the title of the question, since your question isn't field-specific.

Comment: "what can I do as an undergrad to not burden my colleagues and PI" the awareness you show by this question already means that you are far further towards this goal than the vast majority of interns. Congratulations and keep going this way.

Comment: _I will be a less useful asset to the lab than a grad student or post-doc_ — [citation needed]

Comment: These big-list questions really aren't suitable to our Q&A format: it's just too broad, with too many possible answers.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I think the more specific question asked by the OP - "what can I do as an undergrad to not burden my colleagues and PI?" - is an answerable question that is not too broad.

Answer (score 33):

To me, the quality that makes a student *not* a burden is the following:

> A willingness to learn for themselves and good judgement about when to stop and ask for feedback.*

If a student isn't willing to try things out and learn independently, then it creates a burden on the supervisor. I really don't appreciate when a student asks me how to do something *before* they do a basic Google search.

Similarly, if a student doesn't know how to judge when he/she is "stuck" and needs help, this also creates a burden on the supervisor (because the supervisor has to keep checking on the student to make sure they're progressing).

The dos and don'ts (to avoid being a "burden") that come to mind are:

- **Do** ask your supervisor this question at the very beginning, to find out what he/she expects from you.
- **Do** take detailed notes when you have a meeting with your supervisor or somebody teaches you how to do something, so you can refer to them later
- **Do** keep a written record of your own attempts and progress (such as a lab notebook) to show your supervisor during meetings
- **Do** ask a question if you don't understand an instruction or something that is said, because it will be much better for everyone involved if you clear things up sooner rather than later.
- **Do** mention your own ideas to your supervisor, if you have some that you think will make your research better.
- **Don't** think that just because you are an undergraduate, you can't make much of a contribution. Obviously experience helps, but it's really only a small piece of what makes someone a skilled researcher. Willingness to learn is a much bigger piece, IMO. I've had high-school summer interns who were better than any of the M.S. students in the lab, simply because they put in more effort to *learn*.

* Source of the quote: *The Unwritten Rules of PhD Research*, by Marian Petre & Gordon Rugg

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the same formula would apply in most non-academic roles. Almost all jobs involved being instructed by others at some point. Aside from knowing whether you can progress on your own, also develop an idea of the relative value of your time and other people's. e.g asking someone else to spend 5 minutes explaining something that would take you 10 minutes to work out on your own, is *not* a good use of 10 person-minutes, unless their time is worth less than yours. And maybe not even then because you interrupted them, so you cost them more than 5 minutes productive work.

Comment: ... and not asking for help when you're stuck doesn't just create a burden on the supervisor to check on you, it also means that for the whole time you're stuck you're not achieving anything. On the reasonable assumption that your supervisor wants you to achieve something, they would want to un-stick you once you're stuck. Getting that balance right is a lot about self-awareness but also reading cues from the supervisor, asking for feedback, and accepting criticism/correction.

Comment: I love that book. it's excellent.

Comment: @SteveJessop: and in addition is something that needs to be *learned* (as in try and possibly fail many times). As a mentor I learned that many good students are shy in terms of asking to get unstuck. (In constrast, many bad students tend to be not shy at all and unable to read clues when not to disturb). (I attribute it to a thourough training to exam situations where you are not allowed to ask if getting stuck)

Answer (score 5):

The purpose of REU/SURF programs is to educate undergraduates about research, and to encourage them to make good decisions about graduate school.  Secondary benefits include advancing science and the careers of the participants. Note that these are not the same goals as of a PhD program (such as in ff524's answer).

The very natural desire to be a "skilled and efficient researcher" is orthogonal to these goals; in some circumstances it will be counterproductive to be skilled and efficient.  Your supervisor sees the whole project while you only see what's been set in front of you.

You should set your goals as:

1. To learn as many details of the lab dynamic as possible.
2. To participate in the lab dynamic in the manner you are expected to.
3. To do the tasks you are assigned in a skilled and efficient manner.
4. To noticeably improve in your abilities and understanding, over the course of the program.
5. (stretch goal) To have a good and creative idea that transcends the tasks you were assigned.  Share this idea with your supervisor; do not just implement it.  Do this at most once during the summer.

To expand a bit on (2): Listen carefully, including to body language.  Your supervisor has a role in  mind for you.    Different faculty have different expectations with regards to issues such as creativity, asking questions, frequency of meetings, quality control, etc. You need to meet these expectations as well as you can.  Exceeding expectations may not be a good thing; that's why I recommend doing it at most once.

Comment: _Exceeding expectations may not be a good thing; that's why I recommend doing it at most once_ - What does this mean?

Comment: If you are given task A, and you do tasks A and B.  Or, in a discussion, you are told to use method A, and you point out that method B may be better.

Comment: I completely disagree - if you think you _can_ do better than what your advisor tells you to do, you should absolutely speak up and suggest it.

Comment: I agree that that final comment really needs to be explained. Why would it be bad to exceed expectations?

Comment: It is bad to exceed expectations because of the likelihood of wasting time, both your own and the supervisor's.  Keep in mind that this is an undergraduate, not a PhD student/postdoc.

Comment: Undergrads are perfectly capable of having ideas that  save time and improve the quality of the research (I have supervised several). If you think you have an idea, _speak up_ - the worst that can happen is that your supervisor will explain why it isn't suitable (which is no big deal, wastes 2 minutes at most, and you'll learn something from it). The best that can happen is that it will be a really good idea that makes the research much better!

Comment: Look, I don't want to get in an extended debate here.  The supervisor sets the parameters -- be creative in the areas where creativity is encouraged.  Being creative "outside the box" is unlikely to lead to an outcome the OP wants, and in a lab science might even lead to someone getting hurt.

Comment: I think this may be very field-specific - I see that you're in mathematics, where the role of undergrads in research is quite different than many other fields. In any event, acting on a "creative" idea _without_ consulting your supervisor first can be bad - but I am always pleased when a student I am working with (undergrad, grad, or other) makes a suggestion.

Comment: ... particularly as it also shows very clearly that the student *does* put his mind on the problem. In any case, as a student (and also later on) you can always formulate it as a question: "What are the reasons for approaching the problem this way and not say, from that (=new idea) angle?". For an undergrad internship the answer is usually known ;-). The point where I draw a line is that depending on how sensitive the lab equipment is, I may not like the idea of students trying out ideas on their own without consulting me first. If it was not a good idea: *I* have to realign the instrument...

Comment: In my master's project (being completely new to the field) I have had several discussions with my supervisor about techniques and approaches. I would say half of the time he was right and the other half I was. He has the experience, but I have been working with my data set and thinking about it much more than he has, so we both have very different perspectives. The risks of not following their advice are wasting time (the summer is limited) in something leading nowhere and the risk for the instrument. Discussion and suggestions are free in both cases.