# What advice would you give to an undergraduate research assistant?

Tags: research-undergraduate

I'm an undergraduate research assistant on an experimental physics project. I'm becoming aware that the skill set I learned from my classroom learning doesn't necessarily transfer over to the research world. My question is: how can I develop this new research skill set and become the best research assistant possible?

What are traits of exceptional researchers? What skills should I focus on developing early? What are common mistakes in mindset, time management, project choice, etc. that should be avoided?

What advice would you give to yourself at the start of *your* research career?

Please let me know if there is any literature out there on this topic.

Comment: See [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/18053/dos-and-donts-of-undergraduate-research?rq=1) (possible duplicate?).

Comment: Work hard.  Be persistent.

Comment: By the way, there are many books with titles like Letters/Advice to a Young Mathematician/Scientist you may be interested in.